# Insert verbatim content inside a NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: expl3, verbatim, xparse

I work on an environment for setting up exercises with zero or more associated hints.
If I try to insert verbatim content in the body of the exercise, the latex interpreter hangs without specifying an error.
A minimal example that reproduces this issue is shown here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Create the exercise environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ex}{O{}+b}{%
\par\noindent
#2}{%
% End exercise
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

\begin{ex}
Create a new virtual working environment for python
% When the lstlisting environment below is uncommented
% latex hangs with this information in the console:
% Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 24.
% 
% 
% (/home/henrik/.TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd))
% *
%\begin{lstlisting}
%pipenv install opencv-python
%\end{lstlisting}
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

As I interpret this answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489459/1366
by David Carlisle it may not be possible to achieve what I want.

The syntax I want to use in the final version is as follows

```
\begin{ex}
Description of the exercise.
Run the following command
%\begin{verbatim}
%print("Hello world")
%\end{verbatim}
\begin{hint}
Run the example from the command line with the python command
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
The solution is 42.
\end{hint}
\end{ex}
```

When parsing this a headline should be included that presents the number of
the exercise and includes links to the included hints (two in this case)
which are inserted later in the document.
To do so I have to parse the content / body of the ex environment.
The output should look like this, the code for generating this is included at the
end of the question.

[image: Example output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{ex}
\numberwithin{ex}{section}

\newcounter{hint}
\numberwithin{hint}{ex}

\newcounter{solution}
\numberwithin{solution}{ex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\raisebox{1.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Define variables for storing the number of hints 
% and solutions given in the exercise.
\int_new:N \l_hintenv_int
\int_new:N \l_solenv_int

% Open files for storing hints and solutions.
\iow_new:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_new:N \g_solutionfile_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_hintfile_iow {hintfile.tex}
\iow_open:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow {solutionfile.tex}

% Define strings to use in macros.
\tl_new:N \g_text_solution_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_solution_tl { ~Solution:~ }
\tl_new:N \g_text_solution_head_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_solution_head_tl { Solutino }
\tl_new:N \g_text_hint_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_hint_tl { ~Hint:~ }
\tl_new:N \g_text_exercise_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_exercise_tl { Exercise~ }
\tl_new:N \g_back_to_exercise_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_back_to_exercise_tl { Back~to~exercise~ }

% Create the exercise environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ex}{O{}+b}{%
% Start exercise
\bigbreak
\refstepcounter{ex}
\label{exercise\theex}
\noindent
\textbf{\g_text_exercise_tl\theex{}:~#1}
\hfill 

% Run a regular expression on the body of the 
% exercise to count the number of hints present
% and store that number in a variable.
\regex_count:nnN {\c{begin}\{hint\}} {#2} \l_hintenv_int
\regex_count:nnN {\c{begin}\{sol\}} {#2} \l_solenv_int

% If at least one hint is provided start a list with 
% links to the inserted hints.
\int_compare:nTF { \l_hintenv_int > 0 } { \g_text_hint_tl } {  }
% For all integers in the range from one to 
% the number of inserted hints do.
\int_step_variable:nNn {\l_hintenv_int} \l_iterator_tl{
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_iterator_tl > 1 } { ,~ } {  }
    \hyperlink{hint\theex.\l_iterator_tl}{\l_iterator_tl}
}

% If at least one solution is provided start a list with 
% links to the inserted solutions.
\int_compare:nTF { \l_solenv_int > 0 } { \g_text_solution_tl } {  }
% For all integers in the range from one to 
% the number of inserted solutions do.
\int_step_variable:nNn {\l_solenv_int} \l_iterator_tl{
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_iterator_tl > 1 } { ,~ } {  }
    \hyperlink{solution\theex.\l_iterator_tl}{\l_iterator_tl}
}
\par\noindent
#2}{%
% End exercise
}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}{%
% hint start
\refstepcounter{hint}
\tl_set:Nx \l_temp_tl { hint\thehint }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \textbf{Hint~\arabic{hint}~to~exercise~\theex}}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \hfill \g_back_to_exercise_tl }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theex } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \linkdest{ \l_temp_tl } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \vspace{-0.4cm}\par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { #2 }
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { \bigskip}
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { \filbreak}
}{
% hint end
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sol}{O{}+b}{
% hint start
\refstepcounter{solution}
\tl_set:Nx \l_temp_tl { solution\thesolution }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \par\noindent }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \textbf{Solution~\arabic{solution}~to~exercise~\theex}}
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \hfill \g_back_to_exercise_tl }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theex } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \linkdest{ \l_temp_tl } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \vspace{-0.4cm}\par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { #2 }
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { \bigskip}
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { \filbreak}
}{
% hint end
}

% Define command for closing the two files used 
% for storing hints and solutions.
\NewDocumentCommand{\closehintandsolutionfile}{}{
\iow_close:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_close:N \g_solutionfile_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}

\begin{ex}
Description of the exercise.
Run the following command
%\begin{verbatim}
%print("Hello world")
%\end{verbatim}
\begin{hint}
Run the example from the command line with the python command
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
The solution is 42.
\end{hint}
\end{ex}

\closehintandsolutionfile

\section{Hints}
\input{hintfile.tex}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, you can place and save the verbatim into a box before entering the `ex` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{ex}
\numberwithin{ex}{section}

\newcounter{hint}
\numberwithin{hint}{ex}

\newcounter{solution}
\numberwithin{solution}{ex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\raisebox{1.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Define variables for storing the number of hints 
% and solutions given in the exercise.
\int_new:N \l_hintenv_int
\int_new:N \l_solenv_int

% Open files for storing hints and solutions.
\iow_new:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_new:N \g_solutionfile_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_hintfile_iow {hintfile.tex}
\iow_open:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow {solutionfile.tex}

% Define strings to use in macros.
\tl_new:N \g_text_solution_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_solution_tl { ~Solution:~ }
\tl_new:N \g_text_solution_head_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_solution_head_tl { Solutino }
\tl_new:N \g_text_hint_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_hint_tl { ~Hint:~ }
\tl_new:N \g_text_exercise_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_exercise_tl { Exercise~ }
\tl_new:N \g_back_to_exercise_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_back_to_exercise_tl { Back~to~exercise~ }

% Create the exercise environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ex}{O{}+b}{%
% Start exercise
\bigbreak
\refstepcounter{ex}
\label{exercise\theex}
\noindent
\textbf{\g_text_exercise_tl\theex{}:~#1}
\hfill 

% Run a regular expression on the body of the 
% exercise to count the number of hints present
% and store that number in a variable.
\regex_count:nnN {\c{begin}\{hint\}} {#2} \l_hintenv_int
\regex_count:nnN {\c{begin}\{sol\}} {#2} \l_solenv_int

% If at least one hint is provided start a list with 
% links to the inserted hints.
\int_compare:nTF { \l_hintenv_int > 0 } { \g_text_hint_tl } {  }
% For all integers in the range from one to 
% the number of inserted hints do.
\int_step_variable:nNn {\l_hintenv_int} \l_iterator_tl{
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_iterator_tl > 1 } { ,~ } {  }
    \hyperlink{hint\theex.\l_iterator_tl}{\l_iterator_tl}
}

% If at least one solution is provided start a list with 
% links to the inserted solutions.
\int_compare:nTF { \l_solenv_int > 0 } { \g_text_solution_tl } {  }
% For all integers in the range from one to 
% the number of inserted solutions do.
\int_step_variable:nNn {\l_solenv_int} \l_iterator_tl{
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_iterator_tl > 1 } { ,~ } {  }
    \hyperlink{solution\theex.\l_iterator_tl}{\l_iterator_tl}
}
\par\noindent
#2}{%
% End exercise
}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}{%
% hint start
\refstepcounter{hint}
\tl_set:Nx \l_temp_tl { hint\thehint }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \textbf{Hint~\arabic{hint}~to~exercise~\theex}}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \hfill \g_back_to_exercise_tl }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theex } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \linkdest{ \l_temp_tl } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \vspace{-0.4cm}\par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { #2 }
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { \bigskip}
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { \filbreak}
}{
% hint end
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sol}{O{}+b}{
% hint start
\refstepcounter{solution}
\tl_set:Nx \l_temp_tl { solution\thesolution }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \par\noindent }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \textbf{Solution~\arabic{solution}~to~exercise~\theex}}
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \hfill \g_back_to_exercise_tl }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theex } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \linkdest{ \l_temp_tl } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \vspace{-0.4cm}\par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { #2 }
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { \bigskip}
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { \filbreak}
}{
% hint end
}

% Define command for closing the two files used 
% for storing hints and solutions.
\NewDocumentCommand{\closehintandsolutionfile}{}{
\iow_close:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_close:N \g_solutionfile_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}

\begin{myverbbox}{\hw}
print("Hello world")
Verbatim &^%$&\content
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{ex}
Description of the exercise.
Run the following command

\smallskip\noindent\hw

\begin{hint}
Run the example from the command line with the python command
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
The solution is 42.
\end{hint}
\end{ex}

\closehintandsolutionfile

\section{Hints}
\input{hintfile.tex}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a fine workaround. I would still prefer to put the verbatim environment inside the exercise environment.

Comment: @midtiby Yes, I understand the validity of your desire.  And I hope someone can offer up a solution in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

If LuaTeX is available, you can store and process verbatim content on Lua side, which helps avoid this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{expl3, xparse}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{ex}
\numberwithin{ex}{section}

\newcounter{hint}
\numberwithin{hint}{ex}

\newcounter{solution}
\numberwithin{solution}{ex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\linkdest}[1]{\raisebox{1.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{luacode*}
verb_table = {}

function store_lines (str)
  texio.write_nl("line:"..str)
  if string.find (str , [[\end{ex}]] ) then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
      "process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
    return [[\end{ex}]]
  else
    if str[1] ~= "%" then
      table.insert(verb_table, str)
    end
  end
  return ""
end

function register_verbatim()
  verb_table = {}
  luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "process_input_buffer" , store_lines , "store_lines")
end
\end{luacode*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\CurVerbatim}{}

\newcommand{\BeginEx}{
  \directlua{
    register_verbatim()
  }
}

% Define variables for storing the number of hints 
% and solutions given in the exercise.
\int_new:N \l_hintenv_int
\int_new:N \l_solenv_int

% Open files for storing hints and solutions.
\iow_new:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_new:N \g_solutionfile_iow
\iow_open:Nn \g_hintfile_iow {hintfile.tex}
\iow_open:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow {solutionfile.tex}

% Define strings to use in macros.
\tl_new:N \g_text_solution_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_solution_tl { ~Solution:~ }
\tl_new:N \g_text_solution_head_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_solution_head_tl { Solutino }
\tl_new:N \g_text_hint_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_hint_tl { ~Hint:~ }
\tl_new:N \g_text_exercise_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_text_exercise_tl { Exercise~ }
\tl_new:N \g_back_to_exercise_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_back_to_exercise_tl { Back~to~exercise~ }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN {nVN}

% Create the exercise environment
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ex}{O{}}{%
% Begin excercise
% capture verbatim on Lua side
\BeginEx
}{%
% End excercise
% retreive the content from lua side
% save it in \CurVerbatim
\directlua{
  token.set_macro("CurVerbatim", table.concat(verb_table, "~"))
}

\bigbreak
\refstepcounter{ex}
\label{exercise\theex}
\noindent
\textbf{\g_text_exercise_tl\theex{}:~#1}
\hfill 

% Run a regular expression on the body of the 
% exercise to count the number of hints present
% and store that number in a variable.
\regex_count:nVN {\c{begin}\{hint\}} \CurVerbatim \l_hintenv_int
\regex_count:nVN {\c{begin}\{sol\}} \CurVerbatim \l_solenv_int

% If at least one hint is provided start a list with 
% links to the inserted hints.
\int_compare:nTF { \l_hintenv_int > 0 } { \g_text_hint_tl } {  }
% For all integers in the range from one to 
% the number of inserted hints do.
\int_step_variable:nNn {\l_hintenv_int} \l_iterator_tl{
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_iterator_tl > 1 } { ,~ } {  }
    \hyperlink{hint\theex.\l_iterator_tl}{\l_iterator_tl}
}

% If at least one solution is provided start a list with 
% links to the inserted solutions.
\int_compare:nTF { \l_solenv_int > 0 } { \g_text_solution_tl } {  }
% For all integers in the range from one to 
% the number of inserted solutions do.
\int_step_variable:nNn {\l_solenv_int} \l_iterator_tl{
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_iterator_tl > 1 } { ,~ } {  }
    \hyperlink{solution\theex.\l_iterator_tl}{\l_iterator_tl}
}
\par\noindent
% write verbatim content out and read it back
\directlua{
  local~verb = table.concat(verb_table, "\string\n")
  local~file = io.open(tex.jobname..".tmp", "w")
  file:write(verb)
  file:close()
}
\input{\jobname.tmp}
}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{hint}{O{}+b}{%
% hint start
\refstepcounter{hint}
\tl_set:Nx \l_temp_tl { hint\thehint }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \textbf{Hint~\arabic{hint}~to~exercise~\theex}}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \hfill \g_back_to_exercise_tl }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theex } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \linkdest{ \l_temp_tl } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_hintfile_iow { \exp_not:N \vspace{-0.4cm}\par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { #2 }
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { \bigskip}
\iow_now:Nn \g_hintfile_iow { \filbreak}
}{
% hint end
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{sol}{O{}+b}{
% hint start
\refstepcounter{solution}
\tl_set:Nx \l_temp_tl { solution\thesolution }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \par\noindent }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \textbf{Solution~\arabic{solution}~to~exercise~\theex}}
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \hfill \g_back_to_exercise_tl }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \ref{exercise\theex } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \linkdest{ \l_temp_tl } }
\iow_now:Nx \g_solutionfile_iow { \exp_not:N \vspace{-0.4cm}\par\noindent}
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { #2 }
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { \bigskip}
\iow_now:Nn \g_solutionfile_iow { \filbreak}
}{
% hint end
}

% Define command for closing the two files used 
% for storing hints and solutions.
\NewDocumentCommand{\closehintandsolutionfile}{}{
\iow_close:N \g_hintfile_iow
\iow_close:N \g_solutionfile_iow
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}

\begin{ex}
Description of the exercise.
Run the following command
\begin{verbatim}
print("Hello world")
\end{verbatim} % need one blank line after verbatim, otherwise excaptions occur

\begin{hint}
Run the example from the command line with the python command
\end{hint}
\begin{hint}
The solution is 42.
\end{hint}
\end{ex}

\closehintandsolutionfile

\section{Hints}
\input{hintfile.tex}

\end{document}
```